# Conditions on $c$ such that the inequality dont hold.

Tags: calculus, inequality, derivatives, optimization

I want to find conditions on $c$ such that the inequality don't hold.

$$1-ac(a-2)(a-1)^2 < 0 \ \ \  \ \ \  \text{for } a>2, c>0$$

If $\phi(a) = ac(a-2)(a-1)^2 \Rightarrow \phi'(a) = -2c(2a^3 -6a^2 + 5a - 1)$ and I obtain the following:  $$\phi'(a) = 0 \Rightarrow a = 1, a = 1-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}, a = 1+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}.$$ But then $a<2$ for the critical points to occurs. I don't know what to do next. I want to find conditions on $c$ such that the inequality don't hold.

Comment: Are you sure about your constraints? Consider $a=3$ and $c=0.00000000000000001$. This inequality doesn't hold.

Comment: @SalmonKiller I modified the question that I am looking for. I want to know if there exist an condition for $c$ that the inequality don't hold.

Comment: The inequality won't hold for $0<c< 1/(a(a-2)(a-1)^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there's some problem with the derivative: if you define
$$
\phi(a) = ac(a−2)(a−1)^2,
$$
then $\phi'(a)$ is what you wrote, but *without the minus sign* in front. But if we take $\phi(a)$ as the whole left-hand side of the inequality, then you wrote $\phi'(a)$ correctly. I think it will be easier to use here this second definition, so from now on:
$$
\fbox{$\phi(a) = 1- ac(a−2)(a−1)^2$,}\quad \phi'(a) = −2c(2a^3−6a^2+5a−1)
$$
and we want to know when $\phi(a)\geq 0$.

When there are no critical points in the interval on which you examine the function, it's actually the easiest case: the derivative is positive (or negative) everywhere, so the function is increasing (or decreasing) on the whole interval. Here, with $c>0$, $\phi'(a)<0$, that's why it is decreasing. So, for every $c>0$ your function behaves as follows:

1. $\phi(2) = 1$, so near $2$: $\lim_{a\to 2 \text{ from the right}} \phi(a) = 1$; here the inequality doesn't hold;
2. then it decreases (strictly), at some point passing through $0$, because:
3. in infinity it's negative: $\lim_{a\to +\infty} \phi(a) = - \infty$ (it's a polynomial with negative leading coefficient), so for $a$ large enough the inequality holds. (Then it must be $\phi(a) = 0$ for some $a$, because of Intermediate Value Theorem; and for only one, because $\phi$ is decreasing.)

Remember that this all was independent of $c$. Now, I'm not sure what you meant by "inequality doesn't hold for $a>2$", but this solution covers both cases:

- If you want such $c$, that the inequality doesn't ever hold for any $a>2$, then there is none, unfortunately: for every $c$ it holds somewhere, and for a large interval of $a$'s.
- But if you need such $c$, that the inequality doesn't hold for at least some $a$, then it's all good: for every $c$ there are some $a$ near $2$, such that it doesn't hold (from $2$ up to this $a$, that $\phi(a)=0$).